# wp_enqueue_style seems to fail for local resources

Tags: css, wordpress

Or behaves in a different way, but I do not get it :( :( :(.
Let's see, I got this :

```
$stylesheets_path = get_template_directory_uri().'/core/css/';
    $test_url= @fopen('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css','r');
    if ( $test_url !== false ) {
echo "REMOTE::  $stylesheets_path";
      wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', false );
    } else {
echo "LOCAL::  {$stylesheets_path}font-awesome.min.css";
      wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', $stylesheets_path . 'font-awesome.min.css', false);
    }
```

The point is, no matter how hard I try to make the remote option fails or simply use directly the local one, this last one does never loads at all :(.

Whenever I simply try to load the local option just removing all that code above just leaving

`$stylesheets_path = get_template_directory_uri().'/core/css/';
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', $stylesheets_path . 'font-awesome.min.css', false);`

it is useless and the css never loads. However, when I echo the stylesheets_path.'font-awesome.min.css' it shows a valid url where indeed the resource is located and properly loaded if I browse it.

The remote option loads seamlessly , but the local one no way !
Getting nuts :(